# PyQt QTableWidgetItem .setItem overriding attributes and flags

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to get a grasp on how qt handles this widget

```
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter |     QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
```

However when I 'setItem' item in table:

```
self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(self.i, 0,    QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.dungeonCount[self.i])))
```

**QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter |     QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter**

and

**QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled**

seem to override.

Comment: How do they "override" ? The new item you set don't have the right alignment and flags, or something else ?

Comment: Basically it resets to default (I guess) alignment/flags, since fields stop formatting 'horizontally&vertically'-centered and they become editable (which initially weren't**).

**Initially I mean before editing the field with the second block' of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first block, you create `item`, one instance of the class `QTableWidgetItem`.
You successfully change it's alignment and flags.

When you call `setItem(self.i, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("some text"))`, you're creating another instance of the class. `item` is replaced by a new `QTableWidgetItem`, with default alignment and flags.

You should keep track of `item` and change it's text when needed, something like this:

```
self.item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
self.item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, self.item)

#and then later
self.item.setText("my new text")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setItem` method sets *a completely new* item at the given row/column.

If you want to modify the text of an *existing* item, then do this:

```
item = self.tableWidget.item(self.i, 0)
item.setText(str(self.dungeonCount[self.i]))
```